# Different sdl2 versions. How to use pip3 installed version instead of the debian version?

Tags: python, sdl-2, pysdl2

For `SDL_GetVersion`, the [SDL2 Wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetVersion) states that :

> If you are linking to SDL dynamically, then it is possible that the
>   current version will be different than the version you compiled
>   against. This function returns the current version, while
>   SDL_VERSION() is a macro that tells you what version you compiled
>   with.

Below is my python script to check my SDL2 compiled and linked versions. I discovered that they are different.

```
import sdl2

compiled = sdl2.SDL_version() #initialisation
linked   = sdl2.SDL_version() #initialisation
sdl2.SDL_VERSION(compiled)    #updated
sdl2.SDL_GetVersion(linked)   #updated
print('compiled_version = ', compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch)
print('linked_version   = ', linked.major, linked.minor, linked.patch)
```

Results:

```
compiled_version =  2 0 6
linked_version   =  2 0 4
```

On my system, I have the following SDL2 packages installed:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep sdl2
ii  libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64           2.0.4+dfsg1-2ubuntu2               amd64        Simple DirectMedia Layer
ii  libsdl2-image-2.0-0:amd64     2.0.1+dfsg-2+deb9u1build0.16.04.1  amd64        Image loading library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 2, libraries
ii  libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0:amd64       2.0.14+dfsg1-1                     amd64        TrueType Font library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 2, libraries

$ pip3 list | grep PySDL2
PySDL2                        0.9.6
```

From the above, I understand that `libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64` is the linked package, and the `PySDL2 0.9.6` package that is locally installed via pip3 is the compiled package (I had checked the `version.py` file in that package).

**Questions:**

1. What does "linking to SDL dynamically" in the quote means?
2. How do I direct my application to use the pip3 installed PySDL2
   package instead of the debian package?

Comment: PySDL2 uses ctypes. There is no separate library, it just opens the one you have in system and binds it to python. "Linking dynamically" means using `.so`/`.dll` at runtime (so your program will not work without them, but this allows user to update a library - but newer SDL allows that even with static linking).

Comment: @keltar I found `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0` and 
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0` in my system. Not sure why there are 2 of them but either of them must be where `sdl2.SDL_GetVersion(linked)` obtained  2.0.4 from. I had separately download `PySDL2-0.9.6.tar.gz`  and after unzipping and reading its `version.py` module found out that the function `sdl2.SDL_VERSION()` returns the value 2.0.6. Hence I concluded that the `PySDL2 0.9.6` package is likely the source of the compiled version. I am thinking that when `pip3 install PySDL2 --user`, that caused 2 library.

Comment: I don't think so. Isn't one of these are just symlink to another? `dpkg` says you have 2.0.4, that is consistent with observed results. `SDL_VERSION` gives you static values independent of what actual `.so` is - they're constants in `version.py` of PySDL2 (I suppose it is generated from SDL_version.h during PySDL2 codegen phase and is static for given PySDL2 version). So you actually have 2.0.4 only, but PySDL2 generated against 2.0.6 - not really matters here.

Comment: @keltar Thank you so much. You are right! `libSDL2-2.0.so.0` is a link to `libSDL2-2.0.so.0.4.0`. My bad. So I really have only 1 SDL2 package (i.e. version 2.0.4) although it was compiled against 2.0.6. Have not understood the latter. In any case, I learn from here I may need to check if my SDL2 library is dynamically linked or not (evidenced by the difference in version number returned by `SDL_VERSION` and `SDL_GetVersion') and if so to use the linked version number to update `SDL_SysWMinfo()`'s version argument. Else, default to use `SDL_GetVersion' to avoid the hassle of checking. Correct?

Comment: More or less, although this is a shady deal. `SDL_GetWindowWMInfo` will refuse to fill your structure if versions are different, so I suppose you don't have much choise here. But it also may be wrong if newer version have larger structure or rearranged its fields. It is very rare, and to my liking is the weakest part in SDL, but that's where we are at. Maybe you can bundle SDL with our program so known version of SDL is used, but user still theoretically can replace it (and should hold the pieces when it explodes because of that).